# C# WPF Style TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a custom resource dictionary style for a TreeViewItem, but I am having difficulties with it.

```
<Style x:Key="StageTreeViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ArialN"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="PrimaryButtonImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/TreeViewItem/TreeViewItem_Normal.png"/>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The content/header of the TreeViewItem does not exist. I put "Stage One" as Header of the TreeViewItem, but it doesn't show up. Also, if I add multiple tree view items on another, it does not expand at all.

Another thing:

How can I remove the highlights when I select the tree view item? I want it to be transparent even when I hover over it and even when I click it. I don't want anything to happen, but I just don't know how, I tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is not making it clear how you're setting header of TreeViewItem.
For other part of the question, you can use Triggers for events happening in WPF forms. Also have a look at this link, as you'll have to define a template for changing background color on mouse hover. 
[IsMouseOver Trigger not working in WPF](http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/ismouseover-trigger-not-working-in-wpf.html)

Comment: The "Header" of the TreeViewItem isn't visible at all. That's what I wanted to say. I set the Header through .xaml, but it doesn't appear at all. When I try to expand the TreeViewItem, it does not expand at all and yes, I do have other TreeViewItems under the parent one. But it just doesn't expand.

Comment: I can't get an idea without looking at the code in which you're setting TreeViewItem's header and child nodes, show me some more code.